# Visual Studio 2017 loop auto-vectorization issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vectorization

I'm trying to use the Visual C++ 2017 auto-vectorizer to make the following loop vectorized (/arch:AVX2) :

```
void fun(char* data, char* threshold, char* output, int64_t len)
{
    // Assumes output filled with 0

    for (int64_t c = 0, mm = len; c < mm; ++c)
    {
        output[c] = (data[c] < threshold[c])
                            ? (threshold[c] - data[c]) 
                            : output[c];
    }
}
```

This code is used to compare 2 arrays (data and threshold), and store their difference in output if data < threshold, 0 otherwise.

This loop does not auto-vectorize :

> info C5002: loop not vectorized due to reason '1100'
>
> Meaning : Loop contains control flow—for example, "if" or "?".

Ok, I get that, I need to rewrite my loop so I remove the control flow or I simplify it for the compiler. BUT :

- GCC has no problem vectorizing it
- Visual Studio accepts to vectorize it if I change the code that way :

code:

```
for (int64_t c = 0, mm = len; c < mm; ++c)
{
    output[c] = (data[c] < threshold[c])
                        ? (char)(threshold[c] - data[c]) 
                        : output[c];
}
```

**Why does this (char) cast would change anything for Visual Studio auto-vectorizer ? Is that a bug of the auto-vectorizer or am I missing something ?**

Moreover, if I change the type of the output array from char to int, I cannot get Visual Studio to vectorize my loop anymore, whereas GCC does :

```
void fun(char* data, char* threshold, int* output, int64_t len)
{
    // Assumes output filled with 0
    for (int64_t c = 0, mm = len; c < mm; ++c)
    {
        output[c] = (data[c] < threshold[c])
                            ? (int)(threshold[c] - data[c]) 
                            : output[c];
    }
}
```

**Is Visual Studio 2017 auto-vectorizer lacking compared to GCC ? Or Am I trying to do something I should not be doing ?**

Comment: Have you checked the assembly to make sure it's really vectorized?

Comment: And yes, VS vectorizer is very inferior to gcc's and clang's, and very far behind Intel's.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Yes I checked, it is really vectorized when I cast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply a missed optimization opportunity.
The VS vectorizer has improved a lot since 2012 but it's still quite lacking compared to gcc or clang. Keep in mind that their compiler is based on an ancient codebase, e.g. they didn't even have an [SSA](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/12/03/msvc-code-optimizer-improvements-in-visual-studio-2017-versions-15-5-and-15-3/) representation until lately.

Comment: Always compare all the compilers and especially icc since it gives very detailed vectorization reports: https://godbolt.org/g/eNfR2A

Comment: Yeah I guess I need to admit that I won't be able to vectorize my code with VisualStudio (the example I gave is a much simpler version of the real code I need to vectorize).
In any case, thank you @Trass3r for this amazing website I didn't know about. It will save me a lot of time in the future !

Comment: The problem is that these optimizations depend on recognizing code patterns. Tiny variations can make a big difference: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39597. Godbolt is indeed legendary!